# remix async action function

Tags: reactjs, remix, remix.run

In my action function I'm fetching data from 3rd party api, and it takes some time.
How can I redirect from the action function without waiting for the fetch and if the fetching fails redirect back to the previous route?

```js
export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request }) => {
  const session = await getSession(request.headers.get("Cookie"));
  try {
    // this takes too much time, and can fail
    const apiResponse = await fetch("some-3rd-party-api");
    if (apiResponse.status !== 200) throw new Error("API error");
  } catch (error) {
    return json({ formError: error }, { status: 400 });
  }
  session.set("mySessionKey", {page: 2});
  return redirect(`/next-page`, {
    headers: { "Set-Cookie": await commitSession(session) },
  });
};
```

I tried doing something like this:

```js
fetch("some-3rd-party-api").then().catch(() => {
  // redirect back the original route
   return redirect("/first-page")}
);
session.set("mySessionKey", {page: 2});
return redirect(`/next-page`, {
  headers: { "Set-Cookie": await commitSession(session) },
});
```

Comment: OR  - 
How should I handle server side async error in remix?...

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down into two steps:

1. Run code async (background job)
2. Inform the user once the job has finished

## Run code async (background job)

Remix does not provide primitives to handle background tasks. The way you create a background job depends on your server environment.

- Long-running web servers such as Express.js will run your code async (in the background) even after returning a response to the user.
- Serverless and edge functions might terminate once you return a response to the user (handle the request). Depending on how long the background tasks take, you might have to reach for a more complex solution.

## Inform the user once the job has finished

You are looking for a way for your server to inform your client that an event has happened (server push). Long polling, WebSockets, and Server-Sent Events are valid options here. I would suggest you look into Server-Sent Events (SSE) as they are easy to implement with Remix out of the box.

The solution can look something like this:

Action code:

```js
export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request }) => {
  const session = await getSession(request.headers.get("Cookie"));
  fetch("some-3rd-party-api").catch(err => {
      // emit error event, which triggers server-sent event
      EventEmitter.emit("API error ");
  });
  session.set("mySessionKey", {page: 2});
  return redirect(`/next-page`, {
    headers: { "Set-Cookie": await commitSession(session) },
  });
};
```

You can find [the official SSE example in the Remix repo](https://github.com/remix-run/examples/tree/main/_official-realtime-app).
You can find a simpler example of SSE with Remix [here](https://github.com/jacob-ebey/remix-sse-live-viewers), which is very close to what you will need.